# Filter ui-select dropdown based on sibling ui-select value

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have a form with multiple rows that are repeated in a modal dialog. Each row have two `<ui-select>` dropdowns.

The first dropdown has choices of a specific type, and the second dropdown contains subtypes of the types in the first dropdown. Depending on what gets selected in the first dropdown, I want to filter the values in the second to only display those who have a `ParentId` that equals the `Id` of the selected type in the first dropdown.

This is my markup

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in vm.responseItems">
    <td>
        <div class="form-group" show-errors>
            <ui-select name="ResponseType" ng-model="item.Type" required>
                <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.Name | ngoLocalize}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="type in responseTypes | orderBy:'Name' | filter: $select.search">
                    <span ng-bind-html="type.Name | ngoLocalize | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group" show-errors ng-if="responseInfoSubtypes.length">
            <ui-select name="RseponseSubtype" ng-model="item.ResponseSubtype">
                <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.Name | ngoLocalize}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="type in (responseSubtypes | orderBy:'Name' | filter: $select.search | filter: subTypeFilter)">
                    <span ng-bind-html="type.Name | ngoLocalize | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to write a simple filter that looks something like below, but I do not know how I can access the value of the first dropdown from inside the filter.

```
$scope.subTypeFilter = function (subType) {
    return subType.ParentId === ???.Id;
}
```

I have tried to reverse it, and send the first dropdown value as an argument to the filter and then compare it like below, but it doesn't work the way I intend it to.

```
//'responseType' is the value from the first dropdown
//'index' is the current index of the subTypes being filtered
//'val' is the array of the subTypes being filtered
$scope.subTypeFilter = function (responseInfoType, index, val) {
    return val[index].ParentId !== responseInfoType.Id;
}
```

This seem like a quite simple thing in theory, but I can't wrap my head around it. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

in html

```
filter: subTypeFilter : item.Type
```

in js

```
app.filter('subTypeFilter', function() {
    return function(array, itemType) {
     //...
    }
})
```